# pthread_mutex_init vs sem_init (Unshared)

Tags: c, macos, unix, pthreads, semaphore

I am looking at changing some code that I would like to run on linux, unix, and OSX. There are some calls in the code for a sem_init, but the pshared value is set to zero. I did some reading in the Rochkind book on unix programming and he basically said that sem_init that is not shared is the same as a pthread_mutex_init  because it's acting in an in-memory, binary fashion.

The question is - am I safe to change these sem_init's to pthread_mutex_init, or use sem_open to get a more portable version of this code?

OSX does not support unnamed semaphores, but I guess the other two do. I don't really want to have a separate compile flag to `#ifdef(__APPLE__)` or something either.

Thanks

Comment: If I cared about supporting such a broken OS, I would just make a `libosxsemaphore` library implementing the `sem_*` interfaces correctly for OSX, and then require it to be installed and my app to be linked against it when building on OSX. Possibly breaking your code to work around OSX being broken does not seem like a good idea...

Answer (score 10):

mutexes and semaphore have different semantics. A mutex must be unlocked by the same thread that has taken the lock. So lock / unlock **must** always come in pairs in the same thread.

A semaphore is much more flexible in that another thread can post a token that another thread consumes. They are e.g commonly used to implement producer / consumer patterns. So you'd have to check the program that you want to port if it fits to the restricted semantic of mutexes.

Comment: +1 this answer captures the critical difference and the reason why you cannot just replace one with the other.

Comment: That's a good thing to know. This code was developed in FreeBSD I believe, and it looks like there is a combo of this semaphore and pthreads being used. The semaphore posts and waits are being called from two different threads that are within the same process. I wouldn't have thought this would have worked with that model since the pshared flag was set to zero.

Comment: Then you should really be careful. Maybe the logic behind could also be matched with mutexes, but this then is really a semantic transformation and not only a syntactic one. If it is not possible, you should look into a combination of `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` to have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of mutexes and semaphores are different. It is true that a non-shared semaphore is equivalent to a mutex if it is only used as a binary semaphore, i.e. if its value is never greater than 1. However, this is something you need to determine from your code's logic not how it is initialized. If you are sure that the semaphore is only used as a binary semaphore then a pthread mutex is a perfect replacement. If not you can either use sem_open() for portability or write a wrapper that emulates semaphores using pthread mutexes and condition variables.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to mutexes should be safe in the given instance. If only one thread can enter the given critical section at a time, you effectively have a mutex whether it's written as a semaphore or not. However, depending on how the functions are implemented by the OS, you may get different performance characteristics. It's not something I would lose sleep over, but still something to keep in the back of your mind while testing.

Comment: what about sem_open? I was thinking if I switched to sem_open, I wouldnt have to modify any of the rest of the code that has sem_wait on the mutex already. Sound reasonable? I wasn't quite sure what parameters i needed for it though, I set the permissions at 0644 and left the same value in as sem_init had in the old code (with O_CREAT of course)

Comment: It returns a sem_t, so yeah, it'll work with your other semaphore functions just fine. As for the parameters, I honestly haven't used it before. Looking at the API on linux.die.net, your arguments sound like they'll work. I'd personally go with the least privilege necessary to get your task accomplished on the semaphore, but all of that stuff is going to be specific to your program's needs.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use mutex and condition_variable.
Because in my past work, I have encountered problems caused by incorrect use of semaphores, and these problems are extremely difficult to locate.
However, it's hard to use sem_init and sem_post in absolutely correct way.
Like:

```
// Thread a
sem_init(&sem);
// Thread b
sem_wait(&sem);
// Kernel: Linux 3.10
```

If Thread a starts before Thread b, Thread b may block on sem_wait forever. 
It is hard to assume the start sequence of multi-threads, and thread a may restart when it crash. \

But if you call pthread_mutex_init repeatedly, the function will return EBUSY
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_init.html

Comment: Generally debuggers are less helpful with semaphore bugs than they are with condition variables in my experience, I agree, but this isn't a fair critique on semaphores because it's kinda your fault if you don't initialize the semaphore and give it a non-zero value before a thread has a chance to wait on it

Comment: Yes ,you're right. In this program, the only way to use semaphore is to kill all pthread when thread a aborted. But for semaphore, I think it's better to make it easier to use—like  using init-flag to protect it being initialized twice